# Camera intent for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE does not appear on Samsung Galaxy Nexus(4.0.2)

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I use following code take a Picture from camera and to obtain picture's path.

```
...
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE); // image capture
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + resultCode + " request:" + requestCode);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            userImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        break;
    }
}
```

It works good on emulator and on different devices. But on Samsung Galaxy Nexus(4.0.2) it does not launches Camera app. But it returns RESULT_OK to onActivityResult and I see no exceptions in LogCat.
Please give me and advice how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277287/default-camera-activity-not-finishing-upon-ok-button-press/14806908#14806908

Just check this link..might be helpful.......The issue might be because of file name or path(which would be better if it has no special characters like spaces)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, which may impact matters. My Galaxy Nexus can run [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content) successfully, which uses the following code to request the picture:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

output = new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately the same example doesn't work for me. On my Samsung Galaxy S1, after clicking OK on confirmation screen, the intent doesn't come back to my activity. Is there any trick I'm missing?

Comment: @TomBurger: You should be called with `onActivityResult()`. If not, that's perhaps a Samsung bug.

Comment: no, after clicking OK it brings me back to camera application. It comes back to my activity only after clicking Cancel. Btw, the same issue for instance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221879/how-to-go-back-from-calling-intent

Comment: @TomBurger: Then that's a Samsung bug.

Comment: I guess I solved the problem. I described the solution as answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13185464/412070

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(<Folder Name>) resolved the main issue, I was getting. :)

Comment: @TomBurger: This was happening with me. Make sure your phone has directory in which image is going to store. After that okay button will work fine.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated now. You should use `Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)` instead