# Android:code for camera activity not working for Samsung grand

Tags: android, camera

Android:code for camera activity is taken from http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/
This code work fine in some devices. But in my Samsung grand duos, while running this code the camera became open and possible to take picture, but this image is not saved and not came back to base application. The camera still get ready for next image capturing.

Comment: it is a common issue in the sumsung android moble u just check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470532/camera-intent-for-action-image-capture-does-not-appear-on-samsung-galaxy-nexus4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android:camera activity is not working for Samsung grand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158203/androidcamera-activity-is-not-working-for-samsung-grand)